# How to add values to a second ListBox on a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create two separate ListBoxes in one UserForm in Excel VBA.

By using the following code one ListBox was created, and I added values, but the other one shows ambiguous name error.

If I change name as `UserForm_Initialize1()` or something it doesn't accept it.

How should I add values to a second ListBox (`ListBox2`) in the same UserForm?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        ListBox1.AddItem "MBA"
        ListBox1.AddItem "MCA"
        ListBox1.AddItem "MSC"
        ListBox1.AddItem "MECS"
        ListBox1.AddItem "CA"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like the code below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ListBox1
    .AddItem "MBA"
    .AddItem "MCA"
    .AddItem "MSC"
    .AddItem "MECS"
    .AddItem "CA"
End With


With ListBox2
    .AddItem "Test 1"
    .AddItem "Test 2"
    .AddItem "Test 3"
    .AddItem "Test 4"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Uma Devi Nangana you're welcome, please mark as "Answer" , by clicking on the **V** next to my answer it, it will turn green, and you get +2 points